# Why doesn't my HOSTS file redirect DNS in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, dns, hosts, url-rewriting, hosts-file

I've modified the HOSTS file on my Windows 7 machine in exactly the same manner as I have in the past on my Vista and XP machines; however it has had no effect.

How do you redirect URLs in Windows 7 or enable the HOSTS file so that it acts as it did in the previous versions of Windows?

Comment: Please post your hosts file

Comment: Can you give a specific example? What is the configuration, what steps do you take to test it, what do you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: I second post your hosts file. Also try the hosts file on the XP machine where the other hosts file works.

Comment: Make sure you haven't saved hosts files as hosts.txt accidentally..! Small thing but worth checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally forgot about this open question. [As it turns out](http://www.tweaksforgeeks.com/windows7/2011/02/windows-7-hosts-file-ignored), if you copy the contents of the file, paste it into a new Notepad, delete the original file, and then save HOSTS again to C:|Windows\System32\Drivers\etc then it works.

Comment: This is NOT the standard way when editing the hosts file, you don't need to copy and paste the contents like that. Not every time, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows 7,

1. Open Notepad in *Run as Administrator* mode.
2. Now you can see these lines...

   ```
   # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
   #    127.0.0.1           localhost
   #    ::1                 localhost
   ```
3. Add new line for your domain.
4. After the change it will be like this...

   ```
   # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
   #      127.0.0.1             localhost
   #      ::1                   localhost
          10.40.0.9             xxx.com  
          10.40.0.10            yyy.com
   ```
5. Now save the hosts file. If it prompts to save it elsewhere then you forgot to open Notepad as administartor.
6. Go to Windows' command promt and run this command `ipconfig /flushdns`
7. Open your browser and try to browse xxx.com and yyy.com etc. Should work fine.

Note to remove '#' sign, because 127.0.0.1 doesn't require the hosts file to resolve and the '#' sign denotes a comment line.

Comment: Please, **please** take a moment to read the [formatting/Markdown](http://superuser.com/editing-help) help and keep it simple instead of unwanted garbage HTML

Comment: Upvote because this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running an `IPCONFIG /Flushdns`?

It may be that Windows 7 caches the lookups in a different way to older versions, leading to slightly different behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that amongst many other things. I've currently NO idea why the HOSTS file seems to be completely ignored in W7.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, the DNS resolution order has not changed.